# Where does the expression, "Go scrape mold on yourself" come from? And what does it mean?

Tags: etymology, hiberno-english

My grandfather is from Ireland, and he frequently used this phrase.

I understood it to be an insult, to mean basically "screw you"

I love the phrasing, but have no idea where it comes from. Is anyone else aware of this phrase and knows where it comes from? Or is this a unique saying from my grandfather?

Comment: Never heard it before.  But you can follow “Go” with almost anything in the right tone of voice to mean “go screw yourself”

Comment: Interesting phrase. Does it mean self-sabotaging?

Answer (score 1):

A google search for the phrase "go scrape mould" (using quotation marks, and with the British spelling) returns **zero** results.

This tells me that it is very unlikely to be a common phrase.

Also, it sounds strange. I would expect something like "go scrape mould **off** yourself" instead. Usually, we scrape *off*, not *on*.

Comment: Lexico gives [definition 3](https://www.lexico.com/definition/mould) of mould as "soft loose earth" and it has been used to refer to the earth in churchyards and cemeteries. I wonder if "go scrape mould on yourself" meant "go and bury yourself". Otherwise expressed as "go away and don't bother me again" or "crawl away and die".